# Powershell - Remove lines from a textfile

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove some lines from a .txt file.

```
function save{

Param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[String]$savedPath,
[String]$fPath
)

$parentPath = (get-item $fPath).parent.fullName
$parentPath

while($savedPath -ne $parentPath) {
    analyse $savedPath
    $savedPath = (get-item $savedPath).parent.fullName
}
}
```

The analyse function isnt important here.
When I send him a `$savedPath`, i need to delete the line from the textfile which contains the path + ";", same with his parents. For example :

```
$savedPath =  C:\folder\folder2\folder3
$fPath = C:\folder
```

Then the lines containing those 3 Strings are removed :

```
C:\folder\folder2\folder3;
C:\folder\folder2;
C:\folder;
```

Cant manage to make it work...

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you provide an example of your inputfile and the expected outputfile?

Comment: The file containing the folders looks like that :
    C:\folder;12;2001
    C:\folder\folder;85;845
    C:\folder2;45;9865

etc... It contains diverse informations I need for an other function, but that's not important. What I want to do is delete the ones containing the path i send to the function, if i send "C:\folder" then the previous example would be replaced by
    C:\folder2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used this command :

```
$result = Get-Content C:\folder\logs.txt
$result | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch [regex]::escape($savedPath)} | Set-Content C:\folder\logs.txt
```

Seems like it works fine !